# How come this text isn't being centered?

Tags: html, css

For some reason this text isn't being centered.

```
#highlightheader
{
           background-color:#006600;
           color:white;
           font-size:30px;
           text-align:center; 
           font-weight:bold;
 }​


​<span id="highlightheader">example text</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://tinkerbin.com/eoJprUq5 (jfiddle going too slow, used this one instead)

EDIT: i ONLY want the text to be highlighted, not have a whole green bar across.

Comment: JFYI - that link doesn't works on IE8

Comment: ah, sorry about that. it is working with chrome. i would've used jfiddle, but was not running for me atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

span is an inline tag
add display:block to css
http://tinkerbin.com/oBgV5mcU

Comment: what if i only want the text to be highlighted? not the whole bar across?

Answer (score 2):

Because you use SPAN and span is an inline element. Use display:block in CSS or better p-tag `<p>` or div with width:100% to center your text.

Edit:

```
#highlightheader {
    text-align:center;
}

#highlightheader span { 
    background-color:#006600; 
    color:white; 
    font-size:30px; 
    text-align:center;  
    font-weight:bold; 
}

<p id="highlightheader"><span>example text</span>​</p>​
```

Comment: what if i only want the text to be highlighted? not the whole bar across?

Comment: for this you can try the :nth-child(1) selector. But only works in newer browsers. Or you use span inside p/div

Answer (score 2):

a span is an inline element, whereas a block element like `<div>` would work...  alternatively add `display: block;` to your css.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a div around the span, especially since you want a heading here. As mentioned in the other answers, `span` should be used for inline elements. You're using it right for highlighting but positioning should be done through `div`.

Try that:

```
div.center{
   text-align:center;
}

#highlightheader
{
           background-color:#006600;
           color:white;
           font-size:30px; 
           font-weight:bold;
 }​

<div class=center>
​<span id="highlightheader">example text</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `display: block;` to the `#highlightheader`. `<span>` is an inline element!

Answer (score 2):

Hi there try to use this with your css

padding:0px 50px 0px 50px;

Answer (score 1):

Span is an inline element. This means its width will auto fit to the size of its contents. Instead, change the span to a p tag - a block element. Block elements have a default with of 100% of the parent.

You can see a demo [here](http://tinkerbin.com/C0i4RUwz)

Comment: what if i only want the text to be highlighted? not the whole bar across?